# Controller method questions about creating transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, h2

Heeey everyone! :)

I have following scenario
Two tables - `Account` and `Transaction`
Idea is simple - while creating transaction between two accounts(scenario is that only 2 accounts are involved)

```
- sender new balance = senderAccountBalance - transactionAmount

- receiver new balance = receiverAccountBalance + transactionAmount
```

(I am extending JpaRepositories)

Performing a `@PostMapping("/transactions")` method doesn't change neither `SenderAccount Balance` property nor `ReceiverAccount Balance` property - here's the code for `Controller` method and `Entities`
I need either to fix this option or find out another one as I am a bit stuck for now :{

```
@PostMapping("/transactions")
    public ResponseEntity<Transaction> createTransaction(@Valid @RequestBody Transaction transaction) {
        final Transaction result = transactionRepository.save(transaction);
        final URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().
                path("/{id}")
                .buildAndExpand(result.getId()).toUri();
        Integer emitterBalance = accountRepository.findById(transaction.getSenderAccountId()).get().getBalance();
        Integer receptorBalance = accountRepository.findById(transaction.getReceiverAccountId()).get().getBalance();
        Integer amount = transactionRepository.findById(transaction.getId()).get().getAmount();
        Integer emitterFinalBalance = emitterBalance - amount;
        Integer receptorFinalBalance = receptorBalance + amount;
        accountRepository.findById(transaction.getSenderAccountId()).get().setBalance(emitterFinalBalance);
        accountRepository.findById(transaction.getReceiverAccountId()).get().setBalance(receptorFinalBalance);
        return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
    }
```

Account.class

```
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String holder;

    @NotNull
    private Integer balance;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "emitterId",fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Transaction> transactionsMade;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "receptorId",fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Transaction> transactionsReceived;

    public Account(String holder, Integer balance){
        this.holder = holder;
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public Account(Long id){
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Transaction.class

```
public class Transaction {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private Integer amount;

    @NotNull
    private Instant created;

    @NotNull
    private Long senderAccountId;

    @NotNull
    private Long receiverAccountId;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "emitterId")
    private Account emitterId;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "receptorId")
    private Account receptorId;

    public Transaction(Long id,Integer amount, Account emitterId, Account receptorId){
        this.created = Instant.now();
        this.amount = amount;
        this.emitterId = emitterId;
        this.receptorId = receptorId;
        this.id = id;
        senderAccountId = this.emitterId.getId();
        receiverAccountId = this.receptorId.getId();
    }

}
```

Could you help me to solve this issue?
Thank You in advace! :)

Comment: Your method needs to be Transactional. Otherwise you're only modifying detached objects. And please, use variables, don't call Optional.get(), and learn about associations between entities: a Transaction shouldn't have the IDs of the accounts. It should have the accounts themeselves.

Answer (score 1):

Just mark your method as `@Transactional`.

Without that the repository returns entities in *detached* state (modification are not tracked), and to save modification you have to save them explicitly by calling  `repository.save(entity)`. Like this:

```
 @PostMapping("/transactions")
 public ResponseEntity<Transaction> createTransaction(@Valid @RequestBody Transaction transaction) {
   ...
   var senderAccount = accountRepository.findById(transaction.getSenderAccountId()).get();
   senderAccount.setBalance(emitterFinalBalance);
   accountRepository.save(senderAccount);

   var receiverAccount = accountRepository.findById(transaction.getReceiverAccountId()).get();
   receiverAccount.setBalance(receptorFinalBalance);
   accountRepository.save(receiverAccount);

   return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
}
```

Having a transactional method changes this behaviour, and repository returns entities in *attached* state, this means that Hibernate will track all the changes in those entities, and all the updates will be sent to DB on the end of the method. To have this behaviour you have to mark this method as a `@Transactional`:

```
@PostMapping("/transactions")
@Transactional
public ResponseEntity<Transaction> createTransaction(@Valid @RequestBody Transaction transaction) {
    ...
```

Comment: Hey Max, thank you for reply but I didn't understand a bit the part about calling explicitly repository.save(entity) - could you help me to fix the part of code to clarify me this aspect, please?

Comment: @PavelS I have updated the answer with examples, please have a look. And keep in mind that only `@Transactional` method is done inside a single transaction. If  method is not transactional, then every DB operation (each  save) is done in separate  transaction.